# How do I fire a jQuery with an option selected from a Select2 dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I am using Select2 for my dropdown styling. The options are then output like

```
<option value="001,100">Option 001</option>
<option value="002,200">Option 002</option>
<option value="003,300">Option 003</option>
```

What I want to do is that when someone clicks one of the options, the jQuery action `loadMap(coords)` is fired. So basically if someone selects the first option, it should fire `loadMap(001,100)`.

How would I achieve this? The docs at https://select2.github.io/examples.html say that:

"select2:select is fired whenever a result is selected."

```
var $eventLog = $(".js-event-log");
var $eventSelect = $(".js-example-events");
$eventSelect.on("select2:select", function (e) { log("select2:select", e); });
```

But how would I get this to launch a jQuery action?

This is my markup:

```
<div class="form-group">
<select class="map form-control" name="map"></select>
</div>

<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {

$( ".map" ).select2({        
    ajax: {
        url: "https://www.url.com/query_maps.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        data: function (params) {
            return {
                q: params.term
            };
        },
        processResults: function (data) {
            // parse the results into the format expected by Select2.
            // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
            // alter the remote JSON data
            return {
                results: data
            };
        },
        cache: true
    },
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    placeholder: "Select your map"
});

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$("#map").select2();

$("#map").on('change', function(){
    var selected = $(this).val();
    loadMap(selected);
});

function loadMap(val){  
  alert("You have selected "+val);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.2/select2.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.2/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<select id="map" class="map" style="width:300px">
   <option value="-- Select Your option --">-- Select Your option --</option>
   <option value="001,100">Option 001</option>
   <option value="002,200">Option 002</option>
   <option value="003,300">Option 003</option>
</select>
```

Are you looking for something like this  ? ?